# How to route URI with a specific Method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I have been searching for the correct answer from the last 2hrs but the already answered solutions are not working, 
I have a Controller named **courses** and a method **detail** I want to redirect only this method to specific Url

My code is :

`$route['courses/detail/(:any)'] = 'courses/detail/$1';`

if I remove detail it works fine but all methods inside this controller are getting redirected to the same Url.
Please give a solution.

Comment: Did you check this documentation? :-- https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

using codeigniter routing method, you can write following code for `domain/courses/detail/123` url, it'll pass the language as a parameter to the function. suppose you have `index.php` controller and `about` as a function

```
    function detail($course_id)
    {
        echo $course_id;
    }
```

then you've to write following line in `routes.php`

```
    $route['courses/detail/(:any)'] = 'courses/detail/$1';
```

now if you hit `domain/courses/detail/123`, then output will be `123`

Comment: Yes , my method is using slug as a parameter but still the issue is same.

Comment: can you put your desired URL?

Comment: my desired URL is courses/web-development , 
and method is as follows :
public function detail($slug = NULL){

}


Issue is if I change it to $route['courses/(:any)'] = 'courses/detail/$1';
it works fine , but all other methods start showing 404 error